# Failure get facebook group id from url via facebook graph (just this one)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already tried lot of topics and follow some groups ok we can get facebook group id, but just some group I cannot get group id it return blank data, I also add token id but it isn't work

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.$groupname.'&type=group&access_token='.$session->getToken();

some group work fine but some group get nothing.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/Happypattaya/

This is one of group url that I cannot get id.

I really need to use graph or facebook sdk to get group id.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

when you search facebook response group id and name. Or you can get group id or you can have it in http://lookup-id.com ( get open/close facebook group id )

Comment: Hi David, thanks but I want just php,graph api to get it into my system not get id by other sites